# White space issue after resizing the browser window and mouseover function to dynamically resize the panels using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my current project, I am in the process of creating 4 div panels with full width and height of the browser. (Note: as per the specified requirements in CSS)

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DayakarKodirekka/pacL5xhb/3/

Here is the issue what I'm facing:

1. Resizing the browser and resizing the div panels leads to white space after maximizing the browser?

whenever I minimize the browser and resize the panels its working as expected but when I maximize the browser window there appears a white space as shown in the image. All the required code I have tried is posted in jsfiddle.

```
[![image after resizing the browser][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN8BP.png
```

is there a way to gain the full width of section2 even after resizing the browser and get rid of white space?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for sparing your valuable time here to address this issue. Daya

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work correctly, I don't see any white space like in your screenshot. Tested on FF and Chrome

Comment: @Arnau: Thanks for your response, Steps to follow to demonstrate the issue. Step1: minimize the browser window. step2: resize the panelA div either left or right(when you mouse over the gray color div , resizer function will get activate). step3: maximize the browser window now. you'll see the white space.